# how to use single css for multiple views?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am creating an application where I am having many views but they all have to use a single css...

I placed my css code in `assests\stylesheets\application.css`

and in my view head part I am adding:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application.css' %>
```

but stil it is not working

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
```

Note the lack of `.css`

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10492888/950890